# Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'Byte' and 'Type'

Tags: android, kotlin, enums

Having this:

```
enum class Type(val value: Byte){
    TOP(0),
    BOTTOM(1);
}
```

and this:

```
val position: Byte = binaryReader.readByte()
```

this line, gives error:

```
if (position == BarElement.Type.BOTTOM)
```

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'Byte' and 'Type'

Can someone help me understanding why?

Comment: Error message pretty much explains what is the problem. What is your expected behavior? How could we compare an object to a byte? Did you mean to use the `value` prop for comparison?

Comment: Of course, it is because you try to compare different data types. You need to use `value` prop of enum.

Comment: @broot the issue here is that Android Studio is telling with a hint on screen that the 0 and the 1 on the right of TOP AND BOTTOM are the property called " value", and value is a byte, so it means to me that if I use Type.TOP it is a byte.... it is not well represented by Android Studio then. Thank you very much I'll use Type.TOP.value

Comment: @ShiroEnnosuke read my previous comment. Thank you

Comment: @NullPointerException I know your problem is solved already, but to be honest, I don't understand your reasoning :-) `value` is just a name of the property that you assigned to it, there is nothing special about that name. You could name it `code`, `foo`, or `blablasaurus`. Why would it become an entity of the object itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BOTTOM` isn't a Byte, so it can't be compared to a Byte. It's an instance of the Type class, which happens to have a property named `value` that is a Byte. You would have to compare the property's value to another Byte:

```
if (position == BarElement.Type.BOTTOM.value) {
```

If you're confused about why this is the case, imagine a more general case where the enum class defines multiple Byte properties. How would it know which one to compare? Kotlin is a strongly typed language and you must be very precise about the behavior you want. The compiler won't make guesses on your behalf.

Comment: Hi, thank you, the issue here is that Android Studio is telling with a hint on screen that the 0 and the 1 on the right of TOP AND BOTTOM are the property called " value", and value is a byte, so it means to me that if I use Type.TOP it is a byte.... it is not well represented by Android Studio then. Thank you very much I'll use Type.TOP.value

Answer (score 1):

This language doesn't have the capacity of comparing two different types of data.
You can compare two numbers, two strings, two booleans and so on.
Even if your Class Type is has values type Byte, is not the same.

Comment: Hi, thank you, the issue here is that Android Studio is telling with a hint on screen that the 0 and the 1 on the right of TOP AND BOTTOM are the property called " value", and value is a byte, so it means to me that if I use Type.TOP it is a byte.... it is not well represented by Android Studio then. Thank you very much I'll use Type.TOP.value

Answer (score 1):

The error you're encountering is because you're trying to compare a `Byte` with an enum type `BarElement.Type.BOTTOM`, which are not directly compatible for comparison. To compare them correctly, you should compare the `position` variable with the `value` property of the enum cases. Here's how you can do it:

```
if (position == BarElement.Type.BOTTOM.value) {
    // Your code for when position is BOTTOM
}
```

In the code above, we are comparing the `position` variable with the `value` property of the `BarElement.Type.BOTTOM` enum case. This will correctly check if `position` has the same value as `BOTTOM`.

Comment: Hi, thank you, the issue here is that Android Studio is telling with a hint on screen that the 0 and the 1 on the right of TOP AND BOTTOM are the property called " value", and value is a byte, so it means to me that if I use Type.TOP it is a byte.... it is not well represented by Android Studio then. Thank you very much I'll use Type.TOP.value